# How to use c# code to add bindingConfiguration attribute (WCF)

Tags: wcf, app-config, wcf-binding

I have an endpoint in the app.config:

```
<endpoint address=""

              binding="netTcpBinding"

              bindingConfiguration="financeBinding"

              name="RoutingServiceEndpoint"
              contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter" />
```

The bindingConfiguration in app.config

```
    <bindings>
<netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="financeBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:10" openTimeout="00:10:10" sendTimeout="00:10:10" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
      <!--transactionFlow="true"-->
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Question is: how could i config this in the code? I need read the config for the database and bind it.
:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this you can configure your settings in the code:

```
using System.ServiceModel;           

EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://yourAdress.svc");
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
binding.Name = "financeBinding";
binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;

binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647;

binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 10);
binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 10);
binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 10);

binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
yourClient client = new yourClient(binding, endpoint);
```